# Configuration change Layout Direction

Tags: android

I have a crash which is from the framework

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setLayoutDirection(int)' on a null object reference
android.widget.ImageView.onRtlPropertiesChanged
android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.setLayoutDirection (LayerDrawable.java:942)
android.widget.ImageView.onRtlPropertiesChanged (ImageView.java:856)
android.view.View.resolvePadding (View.java:13547)
android.view.ViewGroup.resolvePadding (ViewGroup.java:6292)
```

It happens mostly on Lollipop, a few on Nougat.

Do you guys face the same issue?

Comment: Please post your LayoutDrawable class code, the error is on line 942 where the object calling .setLayoutDirection() is null

Comment: LayerDrawable is from the framework

Comment: So whichever object you have on line 942 calling setLayoutDirection(int) is either not set correctly, not initialised or has been GC before this call gets made

Comment: If you look at the stacktrace, all of the codes are from the framework. I'm looking for a solution to prevent `Rtl configuration` change.